# Example how to use predsort(:Compare, +List, -Sorted) in prolog

Tags: sorting, prolog, swi-prolog, mergesort

I want to order a custom list. The list I want to order will be in this form...

```
[n(_,2,_),n(_,1,_),n(_,3,_)]
```

I have wrote a comparator

```
cheaper(n(_,C1,_),n(_,C2,_)) :-
        C1>C2.
```

How do I use this with predsort. I wrote a sorting algorithm using bubble sort, but I have very large lists so it very slow.

Is it possible to do

```
predsort(cheaper, [n(_,2,_),n(_,1,_),n(_,3,_)] , X).
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
cheaper(>, n(_,C1,_),n(_,C2,_)) :-
        C1>C2.

cheaper(<, n(_,C1,_),n(_,C2,_)) :-
        C1<C2.

cheaper(=, n(_,C1,_),n(_,C2,_)) :-
        C1=C2.
```

Be aware that predsort works like sort, there are no doubles ! If you want to keep doubles, try

```
cheaper(>, n(_,C1,_),n(_,C2,_)) :-
        C1>C2.

cheaper(<, n(_,C1,_),n(_,C2,_)) :-
        C1=<C2.
```

Comment: How would I add this to the predsort predicate though?

Comment: Just  `predsort(cheaper, [n(_,2,_),n(_,1,_),n(_,3,_)] , X),`

Answer (score 4):

Joel has shown the basic case (+1), but to get better performance, avoid repeating the test:

```
cheaper(R, n(_,C1,_),n(_,C2,_)) :-
        C1>C2 -> R = > ; R = < .
```

*edit*

Now SWI-Prolog has another builtin [sort](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4)/4, that for simple cases avoids the penalties related to calls of user defined predicates:

```
?- sort(2,@=<,[n(_,2,_),n(_,1,_),n(_,3,_)],S).
S = [n(_2578, 1, _2582), n(_2564, 2, _2568), n(_2592, 3, _2596)].
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to avoid using `predsort/3`. This is an SWI-specific predicate that is not particularly efficient, because all ~ O(n log n) comparisons are executed by calling your definition. Rather try to use `keysort/2` which is a standard predicate and which does not incur any such call overhead:

So first map your list `Ns` to a list of pairs `KNs`, then sort, and then extract the values.

```
n_pricep(N, C-N) :-
   N = n(_,C,_).

pair_value(_-V,V).

   ...,
   maplist(n_pricep, Ns, KNs),
   keysort(KNs, KNsS),
   maplist(pair_value, KNsS, NsS).
```

Comment: I had to solve this same type of problem today and this answer was both the most practical and fastest.