# predsort/3 existence_error [Prolog]

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to sort a list of lists by the third element in the sub-lists, and am doing so using a predicate for sorting defined as such:

`sortData(X, [_,_,Z1], [_,_,Z2]) :- compare(X, Z1, Z2).`

When I try to use this predicate in my Prolog console (`predsort(sortData, [[0,5,2],[6,3,1]], X).`), I get an error stating:

`uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,predsort/3),top_level/0)`

I did some research and found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19613641/why-am-i-getting-an-existence-error-on-predsort) on the matter, but was unable to use the tips suggested by the commenters to fix my error. I tried adding in `:- use_module(library(sort)).` to my code, but that gave a warning upon compilation (`warning: unknown directive use_module/1 - maybe use initialization/1 - directive ignored`).

Any tips as to why I may be getting the predsort/3 existence error?

**EDIT:** My desired output given the call above is: `X = [[6, 3, 1], [0, 5, 2]].`

Comment: maybe you're running an old swipl.exe version ?

Comment: I have just successfully run your query in SWI-Prolog 6.6.4. It yields `X = [[6, 3, 1], [0, 5, 2]].`

Comment: @CapelliC Perhaps? I just recently downloaded Prolog and the console (GNU Prolog 1.4.4), but I may have managed to download an old version. I will look into it!

Comment: @tas That is my desired output (I realize now I should have stated that in my problem, I'll edit it to make that clear). I am still struggling to get my program to give me the desired output however; I am still getting the same error I detailed above.

Comment: @EmmaSteed: I think that's ok, since your problem is that your Prolog doesn't find predsort/3 although you included the correct library. My actual point was that the query works in SWI-Prolog 6.6.4 (which already isn't exactly the newest version :-) which supports CapelliC's comment that your version of SWI might be the problem. BTW, the query also works in YAP 6.2.2.

Comment: AFAIK GNU Prolog doesn't have predsort.

Comment: @CapelliC Oh no! D: That explains why it wasn't finding predsort, then. So I'm assuming if I ran it in something other than GNU Prolog, predsort/3 would have the expected behavior?

Comment: Of course... at least in SWI-Prolog and YAP. Dunno about others... BTW YAP it's difficult to install, at least in Linux

Comment: You tagged your question "SWI Prolog" but you're using GNU Prolog. That's a bit confusing...

Comment: In GNU-Prolog (and virtually any other Prolog) you have `keysort/2` for this purpose. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15443512/772868) how to use it.